# React Material-ui Dialog "open" is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dialog, floating-action-button

I want to make function that show Dialog when I click fab.
but it doesn't work...

I think "handleDialogToggle()" or State is problem.

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const styles = theme => ({
    fab: {
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: '20px',
        right: '20px'
    }
});

const databaseURL = "https://my-app-10a33-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com";

class Word extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            words: {},
            dialog: false,
            word: '',
            weight: ''
        };
        this.handleDialogToggle = this.handleDialogToggle.bind(this);
    }
    _get() {
        fetch(`${databaseURL}/words.json`).then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error(res.statusText);
            }
            return res.json();
        }).then(words => this.setState({ words: words }));
    }
    _post(word) {
        return fetch(`${databaseURL}/words.json`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(word)
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error(res.statusText);
            }
            return res.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let nextState = this.state.words;
            nextState[data.name] = word;
            this.setState({ words: nextState });
        });
    }
    _delete(id) {
        return fetch(`${databaseURL}/words/${id}.json`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error(res.statusText);
            }
            return res.json();
        }).then(() => {
            let nextState = this.state.words;
            delete nextState[id];
            this.setState({ words: nextState });
        })
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextState.words !== this.state.words;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this._get();
    }
    handleDialogToggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            dialog: !this.state.dialog
        });
        console.log(this.state)
    }
    handleValueChange = (e) => {
        let nextState = {};
        nextState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(nextState);
    }
    handleSubmit = () => {
        const word = {
            word: this.state.word,
            weight: this.state.weight
        }
        this.handleDialogToggle();
        if (!word.word && !word.weight) {
            return;
        }
        this._post(word);
    }
    handleDelete = (id) => {
        this._delete(id)
    }
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {Object.keys(this.state.words).map(id => {
                    const word = this.state.words[id];
                    return (
                        <div key={id}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                        가중치: {word.weight}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Grid container>
                                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                                                {word.word}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => this.handleDelete(id)}>삭제</Button>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>

                                </CardContent>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
                <Fab color="primary" className={classes.fab} onClick={this.handleDialogToggle.bind(this)}>
                    <AddIcon />
                </Fab>
                <Dialog open={this.state.dialog} onClose={this.handleDialogToggle} >
                    <DialogTitle>
                        단어 추가
                    </DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <TextField label="단어" type="text" name="word" value={this.state.word} onChange={this.handleValueChange} /><br />
                        <TextField label="가중치" type="text" name="weight" value={this.state.weight} onChange={this.handleValueChange} /><br />
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>추가</Button>
                        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={this.handleDialogToggle}>닫기</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Word);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylFQI.png)

when I click Fab, state.dialog is changed.
but Dialog doesn't work.

if I write 'dialog: true' in constructor, Dialog is showed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKJ67.png)

How can I show the Dialog when I click Fab?

Thank you for answer!